# how to make variable and use in UITableView in swift 3

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift3, httpbackend

I am successfully appending "title" , "url" and Video in these Global Variables but when I am trying to use in `numberOfRowsInSection` as ( `return titleName.count` ) so I am getting nil or in (`cellForRowAt indexPath:` ) as `cell.videoTitle.text = titleName[indexPath.row]` so I am getting nil..

```
Globalvariables is ...
var titleName:[String] = []
var videoID:[String] = []
var valueKey:[String] = []
```

and then in viewDidLoad()

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

let urlRequest = URL(string: urlString)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest! , completionHandler:{(data, response, error) -> Void in

    if (error != nil ){
        print(error.debugDescription)
    } else { 

        do{
    if let jsonObject = try?JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject] {
        if let itemsArray = jsonObject?["items"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]{
            for snippetArray in itemsArray{
                if var snippet = snippetArray["snippet"] as? [String : AnyObject]{
                    if let titleItems = snippet["title"] as? String{
                        self.titleName.append(titleItems)

                    }
                    if let thumbnail = snippet["thumbnails"] as? [String : AnyObject]{
                        if let highValue = thumbnail["high"] as? [String : AnyObject]{
                            if let urlValueKey = highValue ["url"] as? String{
                                self.valueKey.append(urlValueKey)
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    if let resource = snippet["resourceId"] as? [String : AnyObject]{
                        if let videoId = resource["videoId"] as? String{
                            self.videoID.append(videoId)
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
            }

        }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}).resume()

tableView.reloadData()
```

}

and here is the JSOn....

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/ep-DtNxjJwMQbpCO1Lk3_ggMScU\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1636,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/SYrDBZ2Ywgpf3zgCreEdB4PIf1o\"",
   "id": "UUZwDRPIG5DD2lxeCjap51NdbKiDO_M62c",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-06-25T01:50:54.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA",
    "title": "The Google app: Summer",
    "description": "\"OK Google, when is Summer over?\"\n\nTalk to Google to get answers, find stuff nearby, and get things done. The Google app. Available on iOS and Android. \n\nDownload the app here: http://www.google.com/search/about/download/",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BVGKskYZrw8/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BVGKskYZrw8/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BVGKskYZrw8/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BVGKskYZrw8/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BVGKskYZrw8/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Google",
    "playlistId": "UUK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA",
    "position": 0,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "BVGKskYZrw8"
    }
   }
  },
  ... MORE ITEMS ...
 ]
}
```

Comment: Try parsing your JSON with [Object Mapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper). It will save you from all these conditions. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734982/parsing-nested-array-of-dictionaries-using-object-mapper/41735194#41735194) is an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataTask(with` works asynchronously. Move `tableView.reloadData()` **into** the completion block at the end of the closure.

Two notes:

- A JSON dictionary in Swift 3 is `[String:Any]`.
- You are discouraged from using multiple arrays as data source. Use a custom struct or class.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippets above missing the portion where you retrieve the JSON into the `data` that was later used by the `JSONSerialization` in `viewDidLoad()`.

As example of a complete snippet, please check the question in this thread: [How to get json to populate UITableView in Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42016459/8078994)